# Не прорисовывается контур у квадратов в Swing

Tags: java, swing, awt, desktop

Пытаюсь нарисовать через через метод paint(Graphics g) белые и оранжевые клетки, оранжевые клетки с белым контуром. Но не у всех оранжевых клеток прорисовывается контур. Можете помочь?

Код метода

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

        super.paint(g);

        Random random = new Random(180);

        for (int x = 30; x <= 300; x += 30) {
            for (int y = 60; y <= 330; y += 30) {

                if (random.nextBoolean()) {
                    g.setColor(new Color(255, 79, 0));
                    g.fillRect(x, y, 100, 150);
                    g.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));
                    g.drawRect(x, y, 100, 150);
                } else {
                    g.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));
                    g.fillRect(x, y, 100, 150);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, нашёл ошибку в коде

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

        super.paint(g);

        Random random = new Random(180);

        for (int x = 30; x <= 300; x += 30) {
            for (int y = 60; y <= 330; y += 30) {

                if (random.nextBoolean()) {
                    g.setColor(new Color(255, 79, 0));
                    g.fillRect(x, y, 30, 30);
                    g.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));
                    g.drawRect(x, y, 30, 30);
                } else {
                    g.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));
                    g.fillRect(x, y, 30, 30);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

По осям X и Y я перемещался с шагом 30 пикселей, а фигуры создавал с размером 100 на 150, соответственно нужно было, либо изменить шаг, либо размеры фигур.